# Add "synonyms" as an option in when right clicking a word in Chrome?

Tags: chrome

Is there a way in Google Chrome to add a similar function from Microsoft Word via a extension to integrate a similar feature/option know as this in when right clicking a word in Google Chrome?

[image]

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Thesaurus: Synonym 4 Right Click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/thesaurus-synonym-4-right/lpkpcliecpgjbkffooidajhakoidhidh):

- select a word, right click, click 'synonym for [word]'
- easy-to-use
- also uses Urban Dictionary for 'slang' words

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me at least. When I right click a word it doesnt show up besides nimbus screen shot and plus reading the reviews, it doesn't sound to promising since some say "every single word, no matter if it was dog and then cat, gives the same list of synonyms and none of them are actually synonyms for the word you are searching, or even any word on the page."

Comment: Also some others reported the same thing.

Comment: @アズーサ I don't know why this is happening. And as for the reviews, those problems have never happened for me and I've been using this for a few months now. Have you made sure you restarted Chrome after installing the extension?

Comment: I installed this out of curiosity, it works great.  Note you must highlight the word, you must restart chrome.  It also mentions it does not work on youtube comments nor google+

Comment: @James yes you need to highlight the word and restart. I never knew about YouTube and Google plus, so thanks